# Extract the survival times vector from survival object in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to extract the vector with survival times from a survival object in R.

**Sample data** (simulated from exponential model):

```
library(survival)

set.seed(123)
x <- Surv(rexp(100, rate = 0.001))
```

Its structure is as follows:

```
str(x)

 Surv [1:100, 1:2]  843.5  576.6 1329.1   31.6   56.2  316.5  314.2  145.3 2726.2   29.2 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "time" "status"
 - attr(*, "type")= chr "right"
```

**Question**

How do I extract the vector with survival times only? I tried the `unlist()` and `unname()` functions, but without succes.

**Expected output**

```
> vector_survival_times
[1] 843.5  576.6 1329.1   31.6   56.2  316.5  314.2  145.3 2726.2   29.2 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract data from a survival object (`Surv()` function), you can use subsetting:

```
library(survival)

set.seed(123)
x <- Surv(rexp(100, rate = 0.001))

# Subsetting
x[,1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to fit the model with `survfit()` first:

```
library(survival)
set.seed(123)
su = Surv(rexp(100, rate = 0.001))
model = survfit(su~1)

model$surv
```

Comment: I was actually wondering how to extract the vector from the `Surv()` function and not from the `survfit()` function. Is that possible?